# Access Violation при обработке исключения внутри сопрограммы

Tags: c++, windows, boost, visual-studio-2015

Если кинуть исключение внутри сопрограммы и выполнить yield/resume, то получим Access Violation.
Этот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::asio;
    using std::chrono::seconds;
    using yield_completion_t = detail::async_result_init< yield_context, void () >;

    io_service ios;

    spawn( ios, [&ios]( auto yield )
    {
        try
        {
            throw std::runtime_error{ "" };
        }
        catch( ... )
        {
            std::cerr << "[1]" << std::endl;

            yield_completion_t completion{ yield_context{ yield } };
            auto handler = completion.handler;

            ios.post( [=]
            {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for( seconds{ 1 } );

                asio_handler_invoke( handler, &handler );
            } );

            completion.result.get();

            std::cerr << "[2] " << std::endl;
        }

    } );

    // needs more than one thread
    std::thread t{ [&]{ ios.run(); } };

    ios.run();
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Выведет:

```
[1]
[2]
```

А затем упадет. Дебаггер показывает внутрь `_FindAndUnlinkFrame` в `trnsctrl.cpp`: `pFrameInfoChain` пустой, поэтому на `pCurFrameInfo->pNext` падает.
Использование более одного потока существенно - с одним не падает, т.е. нужно, чтобы `handler` вызывался из другого потока.

Запускаю на VS 2015, Win7

Как бы побороть это?

Comment: А почему минус? Вопрос с кодом, лишнего в коде не видно, смысл вопроса нетривиальный.

Comment: Что такое AV?(символы)

Comment: Кроме того, если Вы представите полностью компилируемый кусок кода, в котором воспроизводится проблема, тогда у Вас будет куда больше шансов получить ответ.

Comment: @ixSci: Access Violation?

Comment: Сложно сказать, т.к. я не знаком с этой библиотекой, но вот с gcc этот код не падает(можно проверить [тут](http://melpon.org/wandbox)), а это означает, что наиболее вероятно это баг реализации. Скорее всего бустовой реализации, конечно.

Comment: Имхо, следует убедиться, что все захваченные в лямбдах по ссылке объекты доживают до момента их использования. Плюс: на сколько валидно делать дважды ios.run()?

Comment: [Тут](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/issues/18) ещё посмотрите, проблема похожая

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Тут](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11991#comment:1) ответили: нельзя звать сопрограмму из блока catch. Решить проблему можно таким способом:

```
bool failed {};

try
{
    throw std::runtime_error{ "" };
}
catch( ... )
{
    std::cerr << "[1]" << std::endl;

    failed = true;
}

if( failed )
{
    yield_completion_t completion{ yield_context{ yield } };
    auto handler = completion.handler;

    ios.post( [ = ]
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for( seconds{ 1 } );

        asio_handler_invoke( handler, &handler );
    } );

    completion.result.get();

    std::cerr << "[2]" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.